# Oracle, get all columns

Tags: oracle, select

I got this statement:

```
select count(*), 
       article_no_external, 
       article_group_id
  from tbl_erp_article
 where article_no_external != ' '
 group by article_no_external, article_group_id
having count(*) >1
```

I want to group by `group_id` and `external_no`, this works just fine, I get 128 records. But I would like to see all columns not only those 2. I tried to add them to the `select`, but then I get an error with the `group by`. I need 4 more columns cause I need to grab them to make a new record using the selected data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select article_no_external, article_group_id, col2, col3, col4, col5
from (
  select article_no_external, article_group_id, col2, col3, col4, col,
         count(*) over (partition by article_no_external, article_group_id) as cnt
  from tbl_erp_article
  where article_no_external <> ' '
) 
where cnt > 1;
```

If you want to find non-empty varchar columns remember that Oracle doesn't have an empty string. An `''` is converted to `NULL` during inserts or updates. So you probably want `where article_no_external IS NOT NULL`

Comment: this gives me a different amount of records, 200 more

Comment: @BartaTamás: Your old statement did a distinct on `article_no_external, article_group_id` (because of the group by) which is now not being applied. But as you want to see additional columns, a `distinct` probably won't work. You will need some kind of criteria to pick on of the rows with the same `article_no_external, article_group_id` combinatioin.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get all column values when you aggregate your fields for count, sum etc.

Not exacly same result but this may help you.

```
select * 
from tbl_erp_article
where  article_no_external != ' ' and
(article_no_external, article_group_id) in (
select article_no_external, article_group_id
from tbl_erp_article
where article_no_external != ' '
group by article_no_external, article_group_id
having count(*) >1)
```